# Elixir - Difference between keyword lists and maps

Tags: elixir

Just started with Elixir book by Dave Thomas.

It talks about two concepts:

**Keyword lists**

```
[ name: "Dave", city: "Dallas", likes: "Programming" ]
```

**Maps**

```
states = %{ "AL" => "Alabama", "WI" => "Wisconsin" }
```

When would you choose one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the benefit of Keyword Lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180366/what-is-the-benefit-of-keyword-lists)

Comment: Thanks.  I read the link.  Though I understood the technical difference,  I am still bit unclear about when will you use one over the other

Comment: Keyword lists, heritage of Erlang, are used for passing around rather static collections of values such as options, function arguments and the like. They are just lists so they do not have the properties you are usually looking for when choosing an associative data structure, such as constant time access. Maps on the other hand are your weapon of choice for storing and processing actual payload data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a chapter in the getting started guide with a quick overview: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/maps-and-dicts.html

To sum it up, keyword lists are used for options or when you need to preserve user ordering. For storing actual data, use maps.